# raspberry pi darkice Buffer overrun

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to do streaming with Darkice. The console shows:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# darkice
Using config file: /etc/darkice.cfg
Using ALSA DSP input device: hw:1,0
Using POSIX real-time scheduling, priority 98
Buffer overrun!
Buffer overrun!
...
Buffer overrun!
Buffer overrun!
DarkIce: AlsaDspSource.cpp:265: Input/output error [0]
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

I use:

- Raspberry Pi B
- Raspbian Soft-float Debian “wheezy” (I need use Java for other things)
- Darkice 1.2

I compile source codes with this commands:

## codec vorbis

```
cd /opt/
tar -zxvf libvorbis-1.3.3.tar.gz
tar -zxvf libogg-1.3.1.tar.gz
cd ./libogg-1.3.1/
./configure
make
make install

cd ../libvorbis-1.3.3
./configure
make
make install
```

## codec aacplus

```
cd ..
tar -zxvf libaacplus-2.0.2.tar.gz
cd ./libaacplus-2.0.2/
apt-get install autoconf #I need the utility "autoconf" for the installation
apt-get install libtool #and the library "libtool"
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

## codec lame / mp3

```
cd ..
tar -zxvf lame-3.99.5.tar.gz
cd ./lame-3.99.5/
./configure
make
make install
```

## this I'm not sure that I need

```
wget http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/libsamplerate-0.1.8.tar.gz
tar -zxvf darkice-1.2.tar.gz
cd ./libsamplerate-0.1.8
./configure
make
make check
make install
ldconfig -v
sndfile-resample
```

## darkice

```
cd ..
tar -zxvf darkice-1.2.tar.gz
cd ./darkice-1.2/
apt-get install libasound2-dev
./configure --with-vorbis-prefix=/usr/local/lib/ --with-lame-prefix=/usr/local/lib/ --with-aacplus-prefix=/usr/local/lib/ --with-alsa-prefix=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/ --with-samplerate-prefix=/usr/local/lib --with-jack-prefix=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/
make
make install
```

The installation ends fine for all packages.

The params of de file: /etc/darkice.cfg are:

```
[general]
duration = 0
bufferSecs = 1
reconnect = yes

[input]
device= hw:1,0
sampleRate = 44100
bitsPerSample = 16
channel= 2

[shoutcast-0]
bitrateMode = cbr
bitrate = 56
format = mp3
quality = 1.0
...
```

The device hw:1,0 is correct, because when I use Audacity I record fine.

I followed this instruccions: http://www.t3node.com/blog/live-streami ... pberry-pi/
But the problem persists...

I saw other posts talking about this problem, but nothing helps me.

Any idea? What can I do?

Comment: This probably belongs on Super User rather than Stack Overflow. I am able to stream successfully to both Icecast2 and Shoutcast on a Pi using Darkice, both with a USB card and the Wolfson Pi card. I did turn off all services I could. Streamed both mp3 and aac.